# Oracle SQL hiding duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle, connect

I have a query with these results:

```
A | 1
A | 2
B | 1
B | 2
B | 3
```

How do I get the results to be like this:

```
A | 1
  | 2  
B | 1   
  | 2   
  | 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN c1 ELSE NULL END || ' | ' || c2
  FROM (SELECT c1, c2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c2) rn
          FROM your_table);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BREAK ON` if you are using sqlplus:

```
SQL> desc tab1;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL                                                VARCHAR2(1)
 COL2                                               NUMBER

SQL> select * from tab1;

C       COL2
- ----------
A          1
A          2
B          1
B          2
B          3

SQL> break on col;
SQL> select * from tab1;

C       COL2
- ----------
A          1
           2
B          1
           2
           3

SQL>
```

More details [**here**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I vaugely remember thereis a way to get this format in SQL PLus..
Another possible way is as given below:

```
SELECT a.COLUMN_1,
             CASE 
                WHEN a.rnk = 1 THEN a.COLUMN_2 
                ELSE NULL
            END AS COLUMN_2 
  FROM (
                SELECT a.*,
                    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN_1 ORDER BY COLUMN2) rnk
                    FROM <YOUR_TABLE> a
                ) a
```

Comment: +1 Clever! I might have tried something with `group by rollup` first.

Answer (score 1):

This presentation requirement is best served in the application you're using to display the results, rather than in the raw SQL.  You could meet your requirements with a cursor, but it's not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a formatting issue, best solved by whatever you are using to display the output. There's nothing wrong with the query result, *as a query result*.

Answer (score 1):

in oracle, check out the `LEAD` and `LAG` functions.

you can look at the previous row, and if it is the same as the current row, change the value to NULL.